# Why is extra top space generated on table headings?

Tags: tables, spacing

[image]

```
\begin{singlespace}
\begin{tabular}{|p{1.4cm}p{3cm}|p{1.4cm}p{3.8cm}|p{1.54cm}p{3.2cm}|}
    \rowcolor[HTML]{2D87D1} 
    {\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Abbr.}} & {\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Mineral name}} & {\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Abbr.}} & {\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Mineral name}} & {\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Abbr.}} & {\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Mineral name}} \\ 
    \textbf{Acm}                          & acmite                                  & \textbf{Brc}                          & brucite                                 & \textbf{Csp}                          & cuspidine                               \\ 
    \rowcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7} 
    \textbf{Act}                          & actinolite                              & \textbf{Bst}                          & bustamite                               & \textbf{Dph}                          & daphnite                                \\ 
    \textbf{Adl}                          & adularia                                & \textbf{Cal}                          & calcite                                 & \textbf{Dat}                          & datolite                                \\ 
    \rowcolor[HTML]{DDEBF7} 
    \textbf{Aeg}                          & aegirine                                & \textbf{Ccn}                          & cancrinite                              & \textbf{Dbr}                          & daubreelite                             \\ 
    \textbf{Agt}                          & aegirine-augite                         & \textbf{Cnl}                          & cannilloite                             & \textbf{Dee}                          & deerite                                 \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{singlespace}
```

I try to generate a table, but an unexpected space appears on the top of the column names.

Comment: Welcome // Two suggestions. Moving your comments content to your question will be better; via the Edit button. Making your code complete helps in many ways: we can copy and run it or/and learn more about problems via the preamble of your code. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead, for example `{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Abbr.}}` you should use `\textcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}{\textbf{Abbr.}}` . Than your table become:

[image]

**Addendum:**
An example how you can write your table on simpler and shorter way by use of the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkblue}{HTML}{2D87D1}
\definecolor{lightblue}{HTML}{DDEBF7}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

%\begin{singlespace}
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {|*{3}{X[l,font=\bfseries] Q[l, 3cm]|}},
            row{odd} = {bg=lightblue},
              row{1} = {font=\bfseries, bg=darkblue, fg=white},
            }
            
Abbr.   & Mineral name      & Abbr. & Mineral name  & Abbr. & Mineral name  \\
Acm     & acmite            & Brc   & brucite       & Csp   & cuspidine     \\
Act     & actinolite        & Bst   & bustamite     & Dph   & daphnite      \\
Adl     & adularia          & Cal   & calcite       & Dat   & datolite      \\
Aeg     & aegirine          & Ccn   & cancrinite    & Dbr   & daubreelite   \\
Agt     & aegirine-augite   & Cnl   & cannilloite   & Dee   & deerite       \\
\end{tblr}
%\end{singlespace}
\end{document}
```

Compilation result is similar as before, but is a wee bit nicer (at least to my opinion):

[image]